# How to build a stand-alone exe file wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets, codeblocks

How to build a stand-alone exe file with wxWidgets? I'm using C++ and CodeBlocks:

Comment: just like any other application, wxWidgets is simply a library, one word of caution, link the library dynamically rather than statically, all sorts of odd crashes with a statically linked version..

Comment: You can always statically link libraries into your final executable.

Comment: How do I do it? I'm a newbie in wxwidgets :(

Comment: @Jessie you need to compile wxWidgets into static libraries instead of dynamic libraries and then link those exactly like you linked the dynamic ones. This is not different in wxWidgets than it is with any other library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the instructions that you need to build wxWidgets libraries for code::blocks

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Compiling_wxWidgets_3.0.0_to_develop_Code::Blocks_(MSW)

To build a single static library to link with your program

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=1
```

The result should be similar to this:

```
 Directory of J:\wxWidgets-src-3.0.1\lib\gcc_lib

09/10/2014  12:45 PM    <DIR>          .
09/10/2014  12:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/10/2014  12:45 PM           202,752 libwxexpat.a
09/10/2014  12:45 PM           151,230 libwxjpeg.a
09/10/2014  12:45 PM        48,398,492 libwxmsw30u.a
09/10/2014  12:45 PM           223,374 libwxmsw30u_gl.a
09/10/2014  12:44 PM           227,850 libwxpng.a
09/10/2014  12:44 PM            81,428 libwxregexu.a
09/10/2014  12:45 PM         2,830,642 libwxscintilla.a
09/10/2014  12:45 PM           454,846 libwxtiff.a
09/10/2014  12:44 PM            86,432 libwxzli
```

Here is the source code for a minimal wxWidgets GUI application

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/app.h>

class cApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();

};

class cFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    cFrame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title)
        : wxFrame(frame, -1, title, wxPoint(-1,-1),wxSize(600,600))
        {

        }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);

bool cApp::OnInit()
{
    cFrame* frame = new cFrame(0L, _("wx Starter"));
    frame->Show();

    return true;
}
```

Save this as starter.cpp

Here is the code::blocks project to build this application.  There are three targets: Debug and Release which use shared libraries ( DLLs ) and Static which is a release build using static libraries ( all in one executable ).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
    <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
    <Project>
        <Option title="starter" />
        <Option pch_mode="2" />
        <Option compiler="gcc" />
        <Build>
            <Target title="Debug">
                <Option output="bin/starter" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Debug/" />
                <Option type="0" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-std=c++11" />
                    <Add option="-g" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                    <Add library="wxbase30u" />
                    <Add library="wxmsw30u_core" />
                    <Add directory="$(#wxwidgets.lib)" />
                </Linker>
            </Target>
            <Target title="Release">
                <Option output="bin/starter" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Release/" />
                <Option type="0" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-O2" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                    <Add option="-s" />
                    <Add library="wxbase30u" />
                    <Add library="wxmsw30u_core" />
                    <Add directory="$(#wxwidgets.lib)" />
                </Linker>
            </Target>
            <Target title="Static">
                <Option output="bin/starter_static" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Release/" />
                <Option type="0" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-O2" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                    <Add option="-s" />
                    <Add library="wxmsw30u" />
                    <Add library="wxpng" />
                    <Add library="wxzlib" />
                    <Add library="ole32" />
                    <Add library="Comctl32" />
                    <Add library="uuid" />
                    <Add library="OleAut32" />
                    <Add library="Winspool" />
                    <Add directory="$(#wxwidgets_static.lib)" />
                </Linker>
            </Target>
        </Build>
        <Compiler>
            <Add option="-std=c++11" />
            <Add directory="$(#wxwidgets.include)" />
            <Add directory="$(#wxwidgets.setup)" />
        </Compiler>
        <Unit filename="starter.cpp" />
        <Extensions>
            <code_completion />
            <envvars />
            <debugger />
        </Extensions>
    </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>
```

Save this as starter.cbp in the same folder.  When you open this you will be prompted to set up the required global variables pointing to the folders where you built the libraries. Do this once and it will be available for all your projects.

[image]

Comment: I build this static library but I can't build my project now. I deleted the compiled wxWidgets in order to compile this one. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It ays that wxmsw30u_gcc_cd.dll is missing. What did I do? I deleted the wxWidgets that I compiled before I did this to make way for it and I followed the steps in the link and I replaced the build code with your code. Help please.

Comment: What should I change in the linker settings? What file should I look for in it? I'm in the global compiler settings under linker settings but I don't know what file I should link it to.

Comment: The file isn't here :(

Comment: Did I do something wrong with the compiling process?

Comment: It's still asking for the wxmsw30u_gcc_cb.lib. I got these. I'm pretty sure I have the same directory as you do. http://i.imgur.com/UI1ZuLP.png here's the image.

Comment: I did link it to the release build. It's in the picture I commented? Or did I do something wrong again? Sorry :( I'm really a noob at this.

Comment: It worked now but I have a compilation error about sa certain library setup.h I showed the linker settings there in the picture too.

Comment: setup.h is a header file, not a library.  You need to add it to your compiler search directories.  \wxWidgets-src-3.0.1\lib\gcc_lib\mswu

Comment: Now it says I cannot find -lwxmsw30u, -lwxpng, -lwxzlib.

Comment: Yeah. I added the MingW\lib folder to my linker search directory. Along with the wxWidgets-3.0.1\lib\gcc_dl

Comment: here's everything I've got about the search directories. It might help you help me. http://i.imgur.com/BE5u5e8.png

Comment: Complete minimal project posted.  Download and build static target.  when working copy and add your own code.

Comment: The project that you gave me said cannot find -lwxbase30u and -lwxbase30u_core.

Comment: Those are the sharel libraries.  I thought you wanted the static build?

Comment: I wanted tht but when I followed your instructions and followed the starter.cpp it created that error. Which is weird.

Comment: Did you choose the static target to be built?

Comment: Yes yes but when I press it and edit it again, it goes back to the release build.

Comment: Got it. But where's the stand-alone exe file though?

Comment: What do you imagine is in the bin folder?

Comment: Oh so that's what it's for :o OHMG!!! Thank you so much! I can finally sleep. It's like 3am here. THANK YOOOOU!!!